# How to replace double quotes from csv inside a tag using Regex

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I have a csv file which contains double quotes within a tag and enclosed with double quote. Needs to replace double quote inside a tag with some other character.
Eg.

```
"id"|"Name"|"Note"
"1"|"Sam"|"<Note> This is "a" Sample </Note>"
"2"|"Sam1"|"<Note> This "is "a" Sam"ple "</Note>"
```

Desired Output

```
"id"|"Name"|"Note"
"1"|"Sam"|"<Note> This is a Sample </Note>"
"2"|"Sam1"|"<Note> This is a Sample </Note>"
```

Comment: Are the `"` always inside some `<tag>...double quotes may be here...</tag>`?

Comment: yes there is only one tag which is <Note> which are having double quotes inside them it is a text field so double quotes could be anywhere in <Note> tag. Since the field is starting with Double quote and should be ending with double but inside <Note> tags double quotes causing issue to break the logic

Comment: The problem can be solved in 2 steps. *Step 1:* Extract everything between the `<Note>` tag. *Step 2:* Replace `"` with some other character. Would such a two step solution be okay with you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply but CSV file is pretty huge it consists of 2 GB so would be nice if everything comes in one step , I tried the following regular expression but it's not finding all the double quote inside <Note> tag. 
"(?=[^<]*</Note>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<Note>|\G(?!^))(?:(?!</Note)[^"])*\K"(?=.*</Note>)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                 # non capture group
    <Note>              # literally, open tag
  |                   # OR
    \G(?!^)             # restart from last match position except beginning of line
)                   # end group
(?:                 # non capture group
    (?!                 # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
        </Note              # literally close tag
    )                   # end lookahead
    [^"]                # any character that is not a double quote    
)*                  # end group, may appear 0 or more times
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
"                   # double quote
(?=.*</Note>)       # positive lookahead, make sure we have close tag after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]